# Django VideoField

Tags: python, django

I'm want to make a custom FileField that only allows video uploads
I'm trying to use pymediainfo to make sure the file uploaded is a video but I keep getting FileNotFoundError

here's my code

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.db import models
from pymediainfo import MediaInfo
from django.db.models.fields.files import FieldFile

class VideoField(models.FileField):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def validate(self, file : FieldFile, model_instance):
        super().validate(file, model_instance)

        media_info = MediaInfo.parse(file.path)

        if media_info.tracks[0].track_type != 'Video':
            raise ValidationError('The file must be a video.')
```

and here's the model code

```
def lecture_video_handler(instance, filename):
    return f"chapters/{instance.chapter_id}/lectures/{instance.id}/{filename}"


class Lecture(models.Model):
    chapter = models.ForeignKey('course.Chapter', models.CASCADE)
    video = VideoField(upload_to=lecture_video_handler)
```

in settings.py I'm using the default file storage not a custom one

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want write all these code? In your model form, just make sure the `FileInput` widget gets created with the needed accept HTML attribute:

```
video = forms.FileField(widget=forms.FileInput(attrs={'accept':'video/*'}))
```

Or you can add `accept` to your HTML `InputFile` like:

```
<input type=file accept="video/*">
```

If the `FileField` is still showing all `Files` you can use `FileExtensionValidator`:

```
Models.py
from django.core.validators import FileExtensionValidator

video = FileField(validators=[FileExtensionValidator(['mp4'])])
```

Or you can use it in your forms like this:

```
from django.core.validators import FileExtensionValidator

video = FileField(validators=[FileExtensionValidator(allowed_extensions=['mp4'])])
```

Comment: that'll accept any file with video extension even if it's not a video

Comment: same thing, I can upload a PNG image after changing it's extension to mp4 :"

Answer (score 0):

The problem is from your custom validator.

You did should return the validator method from the FileField after you have added your own logic/extension.

```
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def validate(self, file : FieldFile, model_instance):

        media_info = MediaInfo.parse(file.path)

        if media_info.tracks[0].track_type != 'Video':
            raise ValidationError('The file must be a video.')
        return super().validate(file, model_instance)
```

This worked for me.